# Electron: I was not able to create a distributable

Tags: electron, electron-forge

OS: Manjaro KDE Plasma x64

I was able to import Electron forge to my app folder but when I try to create a distributable the following error occurs.

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Cannot make for deb, the following external binaries need to be installed: dpkg, fakeroot
    at MakerDeb.ensureExternalBinariesExist (/home/quenser/ElectronProject/sysinfoapp/node_modules/@electron-forge/maker-base/src/Maker.ts:147:13)
    at _default (/home/quenser/ElectronProject/sysinfoapp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/src/api/make.ts:148:11)
    at /home/quenser/ElectronProject/sysinfoapp/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/src/electron-forge-make.ts:44:5

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

Comment: You've got the solution right there: You need to install `dpkg` as well as `fakeroot` before using Electron Forge. Manjaro has a wiki article on how to do that [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Pacman_Overview).

Comment: Thank you for your help I know now how to properly install packages and was able to create a distributable for my electron app and install dpkg and fakeroot.